# How to abort getchar in a console application when closing it

Tags: c++, winapi, console

I've written a simple command line tool that uses getchar to wait for a termination signal (something like: 'Press enter to stop'). I however also want to handle the SC_CLOSE case (clicking the 'close' button). I did this by using SetConsoleCtrlHandler. But how do I cancel my getchar?

- I tried doing `fputc('\n', stdin);`, but that results in a deadlock.
- I can call ExitProcess, but then I get a crash in CThreadLocalObject::GetData when deleting a global CWnd, because the CThreadLocalObject is already deleted (okay, maybe I was lying when claiming it was a simple console application). I guess this might have something to do with the fact that the HandlerRoutine is called from a separate thread (not the main thread).
- Maybe there's some sort of getchar with a timeout that I can call instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Maybe there's some sort of getchar with a timeout that I can call instead?

You can read console input asynchronously:

```
#ifdef WIN32
 #include <conio.h>
#else
 #include <sys/time.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
#endif
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 while(1)
 {
#ifdef WIN32
  if (kbhit()){
   return getc(stdin);
  }else{
   Sleep(1000);
   printf("I am still waiting for your input...\n");
  }
#else
  struct timeval tWaitTime;
  tWaitTime.tv_sec = 1;   //seconds
  tWaitTime.tv_usec = 0;  //microseconds
  fd_set fdInput;
  FD_ZERO(&fdInput);
  FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fdInput);
  int n = (int) STDIN_FILENO + 1;
  if (!select(n, &fdInput, NULL, NULL, &tWaitTime))
  {
   printf("I am still waiting for your input...\n");
  }else
  {
   return getc(stdin);
  }
#endif
 }
 return 0;
}
```

In such a way, you can introduce `bool bExit` flag which indicates if your programs is required to terminate. You can read input in specialized thread or wrap this code into the function and call it periodically.